# Bevel of a cube gives weird uv results in the corners

Tags: materials, uv, bevel

I want to model a simple room with round corners. For this, I have applied a bevel to a cube. The cube has a PBR material on it. When I unwrap the cube the corners do not have smooth transitions but visible lines. I have also tried smart uv and tried to change the uv map manually but I just can't find a solution to make the material seamless.

[image: corners]

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-Sogq4CzRIv)